# What kills my LED lights?

Tags: led, dc

I use an LED installation for night lighting that uses 2 R6, 1.5V batteries.
I want to give up buying batteries and for that, I bought a DC power supply that gives an output voltage between 3 and 12V. I set it to 3V.
I connected the power supply to the installation and after a few hours a light bulb burned out.
What I noticed is that the light is stronger if I use the power supply compared to the batteries (so I can deduce either that the batteries are older or that the power supply does not output 3V a little more).

What can I do so that I can use the installation connected to the power supply? Does the power supply amperage have any influence?

Should I buy a better quality power supply?

Batteries are in series, not in parallel.
This is the power supply https://www.bueromarkt-ag.de/netzteil_goobay_eco-friendly_1000_ma,p-542901.html

Comment: Details about the power supply? A unregulated wall-wart could easily output much more then 3V with a low load.

Comment: I'd say the power supply kills them. Have you measured that the DC supply actually outputs 3V and not more than that?

Comment: Batteries can be in series or in parallel.

Comment: Many battery powered LED lights are designed to only work with batteries as batteries are somewhat "self limiting" in how much power they can provide. When the batteries are fresh a large current can flow but that will not be for long as the batteries deplete which lowers the current. The DC power supply does not have this property, it will keep pushing the LEDs continuously. It is possible to use a DC supply but you have to limit the current. A resistor in series could do the job. You will have to find out yourself what resistance you need.

Comment: Hey @Unimportant  I've edited the question with the response to your question.

Comment: Hey @Andyaka  I've edited the question with the response to your question.

Comment: Hey @Justme no, I have not checked that (don't have the right tool)

Comment: Hey @Bimpelrekkie thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZnCl R6 batteries have a slightly higher ESR resistance than Alkaline such that variations in LED Vf from 2.9 to 3.1 will see additional ESR to limit the current. each White LED is about 15 Ohms @ 20 mA and rises with lower current and lowers with better quality LEDs, higher power LEDs and also the threshold of Vf lowers about -2 to 3 mV / ‘C rise in junction temperature.

As the power supply is regulated it will have a much lower output impedance than the LEDs or battery @ 3V. (milliohms)

You are witnessing  a slow thermal runaway response with the LED current and power dissipation rising every degree Celsius.

New concept

This is something like the Barhausen Criterion for oscillation, except here for DC. For each ‘C rise in junction temp,the threshold voltage part of Vf drops say 2.4mV but due to fixed voltage of regulator and Rbulk = 15 ohms of say 1 LED, the current increase. So with a 100’C rise in Tj, Vf has dropped 240mV and the added current is 240mV/15 ohms= 16mA above say 20mA, thus exceed max rating of 30mA.  Now the power has risen by 3V * 16 mA = 48 mW resulting in another more temperature rise.  We know a small THT transistor is about 200’C/W so a thicker epoxy case for a T5 LED Tja~ 300’C/W (FWIW) . Thus Tj continues to rise slowly another 48mW * 0.3’C/mW= 14’C
This then causes the ESR to reduce as current rises from the drop in Vf again. So thermal runaway starts slow and then finishes exponentially fast.

My Barkhausen Criteria variation here is the critical point for thermal runaway is where the source impedance is elevated to make the thermo-electrical loop gain=1.

It can be fixed by reducing the voltage to 2.9V anyway possible.

If there were only 1 LED then 100 mV/20 mA approx is 5 Ohms. If 2 LEDs in  Parallel it gets dimmer and drops to 2.85V approx. but now avoids the thermal runaway as the rise in Tjcn and mV drop in Vth of the LED (asymptote around 2.8V) is offset in current limit by the added 5 Ohms in series which is about the ESR of a ZnCl pair of R6 batteries.

### Short Answer

- add 5 Ohm approx. series 1/8th W resistor from 3V supply.

Assumptions

R6 batteries ESR are about 2 to 3 Ohms each

-(+/-50%)

- LEDs are white 2.9 to 3.1V @ 20mA ( modern HB type) not 10 yr old styles.
- voltage regulator is 3.0V and stable

Comment: Equivalent resistance of battery changes depend on charge condition.

Comment: Yes that too it rises rapidly below SOC=10%. How did you like my Barkhausen explanation for DC? Can you improve it SVP.?

Answer (score 3):

Most of semiconductors are destroyed by overheating. LEDs are driven by current, not voltage. Then you use the small batteries, current restricted by internal resistance of batteries. LED can be connected to small battery without current restricting resistor. But not to power supply. LED needs or resistor in series or PS should be current restricted or constant current output with proper current value.

Comment: Nice qualitative answer yet no quantitative analysis., also “needs resistor” is false if you have the correct voltage to prevent runaway or have suitable wire resistance, e.g. 100 mOHms into 4W 4S Alumclad LEDstrip with 0R. And 5 such luminaries all in parallel  on AWG 18 (done that)   So (-1). everything has resistance, you don’t need to add , if you match ESR’s DCR, Rs well with matched voltage.

Comment: Drop voltage of LED is not the same for all LEDs, even from same batch. There is min and max value, real value may be different because of technological variations. Resistance of wires also may vary. Proper design should minimaze influence of that variations, adjusting the voltage of power supply for each LED may increase the cost significantly.

Comment: Not always true @user263983 I supplied custom spec T5 LEDs to one customer for 10yrs @ 100k pc/yr all binned to 100mV range e.g. 3.0 to 3.1 , data from one batched indicated std deviation of 30mV this is due to Rs only.  The clients design depended on 20 parallel LEDs with no resistors added but regulated, so no thermal runaway would occur. No field failures except prior to ESD process improvements and Zener protection added to all LEDs after 1 year failure analysis (mine). I also have many 12V 4S 1W.LED strings that ran for 5 yrs in previous house exterior off a fixed voltage with AWG 18 feed

Comment: These luminaries are used on highways , Swiss  tunnels and Autobahn fed by underground wireless power.  all by proper design without individual resistors needed and all Iv > 16,000 mcd to 22,000 mcd at a specific wavelengths or XY with tight bins. Of course consumer quality may expect far worse.

Comment: Not always means happens sometime. You mixing up together different things. First hobbyists sometimes buy stuff from not reliable source and parameters may vary a lot. Second custom design is not comparable to mass production, things worked at your house may not work at another place. Your statement proofed nothing.

Comment: My statement proved there is a criterion for critical thermal runaway which can be prevented by computing Rs needed by example. My house luminaries with variable supply would work anywhere because thermal matching of Alumclad reduces dT/dI..I have more proof if you need it. But I agree for newbies, adding Rs = variation in ESR of LEDs is adequate. E.g. 5 Ohms variation of 15 Ohms for T5 white. Then choose Vreg for desired current of shared LED +Rs